# Jenkins asking to enter initialadminstration password when upgrading version

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to upgrade Jenkins version and deployed jenkins.war to webapps folder.After restarting the tomcat server jenkins taking to initial set up to register admin user.But i have already users created and assigned with roles.How to skip the initial set up and to to login page instead.

Comment: I too have faced the same issue while upgrading to 2.346.1
I couldn't find any helpful resource online. So, i had to undo the upgrade and stick with the version what i was using previously.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like loading variables from JNDI was removed in 2.332.

https://community.jenkins.io/t/jenkins-home-variable-not-read-in-2-332-1-running-in-apache-tomcat-9/1826/4

To get it working, add the below in tomcat/bin/setenv.sh. Replace the path according to your directory structure

export JENKINS_HOME=/apps/jenkins